# How to use Aerospike Repository in Kotlin Language using Spring Data Aerospike

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, nosql, aerospike

I couldnt able to create Aerospike Repository in Kotlin Language. I got error Aerospike Repository is not found. I use spring-data-aerospike version 3.4.0., spring-boot-starter-web,spring-boot-starter-test dependency in my project. I can able to create Aerospike Repository in Java Language. But in Kotlin I got error Aerospike Repository not found

I want to create Aerospike Repository using Spring Data Aerospike in Kotlin language

Comment: Without seeing some code, nobody can give an answer that is not based on guessing.